# Register DOM events before an element exists

Tags: jquery, dom

this doesnt seem to work, because of the order it is executed.

```
$('#button').on('click', function () { alert('hi'); });

$('<button id=button>hi</button>').appendTo($('body'));
```

is there still a way to accomplish something like this?

for special reasons i need to register events before DOM elements are actually there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, you can do this:

```
$('body').on('click', '#button', function () { alert('hi'); });

$('<button id=button>hi</button>').appendTo($('body'));
```

The first line works because it sets the event handler onto `body`, but the `'#button'` argument ensures that the handler is only called if the event happens on `#button`.
You can use this (with whatever CSS selector in place of `'#button'`) for pre-assigning event handlers to any sort of dynamially inserted elements.

See: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Ideally, in place of `body` you'd use the nearest ancestor of `'#button'` that is already present in the DOM at the time you want to assign the event handler.

Answer (score 5):

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and delegate on the closest static element

```
$('body').on('click','#button',function(){
   alert("hi");
});
```